# Modified StoryBoard UIbarbuttonitem appearance oddity

Tags: ios, objective-c

My Cancel and Next button (dragged and dropped from the object library from StoryBoard) share the identical graphic yet one displays correctly while the other is obviously glitched. Why?

I configure my button theme below. The image "button" is 24x24 resolution.

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance]
 setBackButtonBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"]
 forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance]
 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"]
 forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Image showcasing the problem.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBPd3.png]

Comment: I never resolved the actual problem, but instead, modified the navBar theme color itself, which is a simpler and more elegant solution for my needs than all this custom UI graphic stuff, and it reduces my App's footprint.

navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor /*whatever color*/];

Answer (score 0):

Add image on `UIBarButtonItem`

```
UIBarButtonItem *btn1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(Action1:)];
```

Above is simpla code for how to add image on `UIBarButtonItem`.

Try with above my code , it may be helpful for you.